# Hide selection bar in ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, selection

I have a client that wants an auto-scrolling `ListBox`, and I am needing to make it not show the blue bar on the `Selected Item`. Here is what I mean by blue bar...:

[image: Selection Bar]

...That blue bar over "Task4".

I have seen code like this that will remove it:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();

    bool isItemSelected = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected);
    int itemIndex = e.Index;
    if (itemIndex >= 0 && itemIndex < listBox1.Items.Count)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        // Background Color
        SolidBrush backgroundColorBrush = new SolidBrush((isItemSelected) ? Color.Red : Color.White);
        g.FillRectangle(backgroundColorBrush, e.Bounds);

        // Set text color
        string itemText = listBox1.Items[itemIndex].ToString();

        SolidBrush itemTextColorBrush = (isItemSelected) ? new SolidBrush(Color.White) : new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        g.DrawString(itemText, e.Font, itemTextColorBrush, listBox1.GetItemRectangle(itemIndex).Location);

        // Clean up
        backgroundColorBrush.Dispose();
        itemTextColorBrush.Dispose();
    }

    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

But that code wont work for me, because I am running the selection event in a `Timer`, so I can't do anything like `e.whatever`, is there any way that I can do this, while running it in a `Timer`?

Here is the code for my `Timer`:

```
int ii = 0;
int i = 1;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ii = LstBxTaskList.Items.Count;
    if (i == ii)
    {
        i = 0;
        LstBxTaskList.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    LstBxTaskList.SelectedIndex = i;
    i++;
}
```

And that code makes the `Selected Item` run down the list of `Items`.

Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't that work?  Drawing the items and setting selection are two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank You Hans Passant!! This is so simple, and I tried doing this before, but I must have done it differently.

```
LstBxTaskList.SelectedIndex= - 1;
```

Thanks again Hans Passant!!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int index = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.theListBox.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            this.theListBox.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler( this.theListBox_DrawItem );

            this.theTimer.Start();
        }

        void theTimer_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            this.theListBox.SelectedIndex = index;

            if ( ++index >= this.theListBox.Items.Count )
            {
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        void theListBox_DrawItem( object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e )
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle( SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds );

            if ( e.Index >= 0 )
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString( this.theListBox.Items[ e.Index ].ToString(), this.theListBox.Font, SystemBrushes.WindowText, e.Bounds );
            }

            // Comment out the following line if you don't want
            // the see the focus rectangle around the currently
            // selected item.
            //

            e.DrawFocusRectangle();

        }
    }
}
```